# Javascript: trouble with [Object object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, document.write

I would like to use this to show on the screen at the end 
**Anonym 

re**
But I want to use the variable comments for that and I don't know how to use it.

```
var comments=[{"comment": "re", "author": "Anonym", "likes": 0, "key": "ahFzfmVhc3ljb21tZW50LWhyZHIQCxIHQ29tbWVudBj46qcJDA", "date": 1363460164.0, "approved": true}]

 for(i=0;i<1;i++){
         document.write(comments[i]+"") ;
     }
```

If write this, there is only written on the browser [Object object].

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
for(var i=0;i<1;i++){
  console.log(comments[i].author + "\n" + comments[i].comment); //for author & comment
}
```

OR

```
for(var i=0;i<comments.length;i++){
     console.log(comments[i].author + "\n" + comments[i].comment); //for author & comment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For one, your variable contains an array with one element, which is an object.

So in order to access the contents, you have to use `comments[ INDEX ][ PROPERTYNAME ]` like this:

```
var comments=[{"comment": "re", "author": "Anonym", "likes": 0, "key": "ahFzfmVhc3ljb21tZW50LWhyZHIQCxIHQ29tbWVudBj46qcJDA", "date": 1363460164.0, "approved": true}]

for(i=0;i<1;i++){
  document.write(comments[i]['author'] + "<br>" + comments[i]['comment'] ) ;
}
```

In general I would replace `document.write()` with something else, that makes use of `innerHTML`. This could look like this:

```
<div id="commentBox"></div>
<script>
    var comments=[{"comment": "re", "author": "Anonym", "likes": 0, "key": "ahFzfmVhc3ljb21tZW50LWhyZHIQCxIHQ29tbWVudBj46qcJDA", "date": 1363460164.0, "approved": true}],
        commentBox = document.getElementById( 'commentBox' );

    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
      commentBox.innerHTML += comments[i]['author'] + "<br>" + comments[i]['comment'];
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Object properties can be accessed by name:

```
document.write(comments[0].comment);
```

If you want the entire object, you can use `JSON.stringify`:

```
document.write(JSON.stringify(comments[0]));
```

or else explicitly format the properties you want:

```
document.write(comments[0].comment + ", " + comments[0].author);
```